# jssor: Sliders move with draggable image

Tags: jquery, jssor

I have implemented in the slider container draggable images, which works good, now on drag the slider also starts to move which I actually want to freeze as long I am dragging something around and on drop I want to bind the horizontal drag sliding again.

How to do this?

UPDATE:

```
var $headerimage = $("<img>", {
            src: "data:" + json.type + ";base64," + json._byte,
            title: json.name
            //width: 40
        }).attr("nodrag", "true").bind('click', function (e) {
            clicks++;  //count clicks
            if (clicks === 1) {
                timer = setTimeout(function () {
                    clicks = 0;
                    iGenerateMedia(json, service, structure, id, jsp, items);
                }, DELAY);
            } else {
                clearTimeout(timer); 
                clicks = 0;
                var $parent = div.parent().attr("id");
                var p = $(div).position();
                var left = p.left;
                var top = p.top;
                $(div).attr("nodrag", "true").draggable();
```

But this not seems to have any effect on the draggable object for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will start drag when a 'mousedown' (or relevant) event is detected on any element in the slider.

If you don't want the 'mousedown' (or relevant) event on your element to be detected, please stop the event from bubbling/propagation.

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        //'mousedown' event name is different on various devices, use '$Jssor$.$Device().$Evt_Down' instead then.
        $Jssor$.$AddEvent("yourelement", $Jssor$.$Device().$Evt_Down, function (event) {
            //stop event from bubbling/propagation
            $Jssor$.$StopEvent(event);
        });
    });
</script>

<div u="slides" ...>
    ...
    <div>
        <img u="image" src="../img/landscape/01.jpg" />
        <div id="yourelement" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px; width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: white;"></div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Btw, please use the latest version of Jssor Slider

**jQuery way**

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("#yourelement").mousedown(function (event) {
            //stop event from bubbling/propagation
            event.stopPropagation();
        });

        //for ie 10/11
        $("#yourelement").on("MSPointerDown", function (event) {
            //stop event from bubbling/propagation
            event.stopPropagation();
        });

        //for mobile device
        $("#yourelement").on("touchstart", function (event) {
            //stop event from bubbling/propagation
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Edit:**

I have just updated the package, you can do this job in a simple way.

To prevent drag/swipe on a certain element in the slider, please just assign `nodrag` attribute to the element and its all child elements. When jssor slider detect drag on a 'nodrag' element, it won't swipe.

```
<div u="slides" ...>
    ...
    <div>
        <img u="image" src="../img/landscape/01.jpg" />
        <div nodrag="true" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 50px; width: 200px; height: 100px; background-color: white;"></div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: And how I make it work again? as this needs to be disabled only when the drag event is happening and I need to do this from some piece of jquery script

Comment: I need to update the packing? as I tried to do this as you said on current version but did not work, I updated the part in the post

Comment: Thanks I saw, great job!

Comment: Is there a delay in the horizontal drag, its way to responsive!

Comment: There is 8 ms delay in theory, it's a way to prevent drag from being stuck.

Comment: Maybe you can contact me, we have some changes we want to have adjusted very fast and maybe you can do this!